# Fitting Python Progress Bar into all command prompt window sizes

Tags: python, progress-bar, pytube

How to make the progress bar size same on same line at all command prompt window sizes without splitting into half or even multiple times when adjusting the cmd window size?

def progress bar(stream, chunk, bytes remaining):

```
percent = 100 * (float (bytes remaining) / stream file size)
bar = '█' * int(percent) + '-' * int((100 - percent))
print(f"\r Downloading:  |{bar}|{percent:.2f}%", end="\r")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Determine Terminal width
   You can use [os.get_terminal_size()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) to do that

```py
width = os.get_terminal_size().columns
```

2. Determine the size of the rest of your text
3. Use your percentages as a ratio to calculate how much bar character(█) and fill character(-) to use to fill the remainder.

```py
   remainder = width - len_text
   bar_chars = int(percent/100) * remainder
   fill_chars = remainder - bar_chars
   bar = '█' * bar_chars + '-' * fill_chars
```

If you are ok with it being off on a window resize until it's redrawn, then you're done. If you want it to redraw immediately, you need to add a signal handler for [signal.SIGWINCH](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGWINCH).

Now all that being said, you could just use a library like [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) that already handles all of this and includes other features like color and multiple progress bars.

```py
import enlighten

manager = enlighten.get_manager()
pbar = manager.counter(total=file_size, desc='Downloading', unit='bytes')

# This part will vary based on your implementation, but here is an example
while len(data) < file_size:
   chunk = get_next_chunk()
   data += chunk
   pbar.update(len(chunk))
```

There's an example [ftp downloader](https://github.com/Rockhopper-Technologies/enlighten/blob/master/examples/ftp_downloader.py) in the repo.